# java.awt.Robot kepress not working for JPasswordField when using KeyEvent.VK_COMPOSE key and character combinations

Tags: java, swing, awtrobot

java.awt.Robot kepress not working for JPasswordField when using KeyEvent.VK_COMPOSE key and character combinations

I have a swing application with virtual keyboard and is running in Linux. When I click on a textfield, I open virtual keyboard and user can click keys and is able to input.

In Linux , we need to support some compose key characters.

> Eg : Pressing Compose Key and then pressing key 's' twice gives ß

What I do in my virtual keyboard is when user presses Compose key, Using java.awt.Robot.kepress I do the keypress of KeyEvent.VK_COMPOSE. And then when a is pressed I do robot.kepress(83) annd when a is pressed again I do the same thing.

Below is what I do overall.

```
Robot robot = new Robot();

// On pressing compose Key
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_COMPOSE);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_COMPOSE);


int c = 83; // Key s

// On First Press
robot.keyPress(c);
robot.keyRelease(c);

//On Second Press
robot.keyPress(c);
robot.keyRelease(c);
```

The above is working for JTextfield. When I press compose key & then press s twice, text field shows **ß**. So it's working fine

But the same is not working in JPasswordField. On pressing compose and s once, nothing gets printed in field as expected. But on second press, password field prints the dot. But when I check the value, **it's s not ß**

What's the reason for it? Is there any limitation in JPasswordField or Robot?

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Have you tried running the application (or just the keyboard) with `sudo`? `java.awt.Robot` has some limitations when it comes to sending input to targets with higher privileges or generally anything the system may protect from your application. Also: I assume you have checked, that the `JPaswordField` is not the issue.